# How do I make collision between two classes?

Tags: processing, collision

I need help and as quick as possible<3 So this is the code and I want the game to stop when the face class touches the enemy class!! With collision or something else. I have the face, main, eye, enemy, message class. I have already asked this question but i tried putting it all together and it didn't work. Please help me thanks a lot<3

```
Face f1;
Enemy e1,e2,e3,e4;
Message m1, m2, m3, m4;
int currentTime;
int enemy;


void setup()
{
  size (600,600);
  f1=new Face(50,200,300,0,255,0); 
  e1 = new Enemy(200,300,30,-5,255,0,0);
  e2=new Enemy(400,200,40,-8,255,0,0);
  e3=new Enemy(100,500,50,-7,255,0,0);
  e4=new Enemy(550,400,30,-6,255,0,0);
  m1 = new Message(width/2, height/2,    1000,4000, "wear a mask");
  m2 = new Message(width/2, height/2, 5000,9000, "avoid contacts");
  m3 = new Message(width/2, height/2, 10000,14000, "wash your hands");
  m4 = new Message(width/2, height/2, 15000,19000, "stay safe");
  
}
 



void draw()
{
  background (0);
  currentTime = millis();
  f1.display();
  e1.move();
  e1.display();
  e2.display();
  e2.move();
  e3.display();
  e3.move();
  e4.display();
  e4.move();
  m1.setTime(currentTime);
  m2.setTime(currentTime);
  m3.setTime(currentTime);
  m4.setTime(currentTime);
  m1.display();
  m2.display();
  m3.display();
  m4.display();
  
 



  fill(35, 20, 219);
  rect(200, 240, 180, 30); 
  rect(0, 0, 600, 10); 
  rect(0, 0, 10, 600); 
  rect(0, 590, 600, 10);
  rect(590, 0, 10, 600);
  rect(40, 50, 50, 20);
  rect(140, 50, 50, 20);
  rect(0, 220, 40, 140);
  rect(0, 400, 40, 20);
  rect(80, 580, 200, 20);
  rect(340, 580, 200, 20);
  rect(240, 500, 150, 20);
  rect(300, 500, 20, 50);
  rect(240, 380, 150, 20);
  rect(300, 380, 20, 70);
  rect(390, 450, 60, 15);
  rect(500, 450, 90, 15);
  rect(500, 480, 20, 50);
  rect(120, 420, 20, 80);
  rect(90, 500, 90, 20);
  rect(280, 0, 20, 60);
  rect(380, 50, 40, 20);
  rect(480, 50, 40, 20);
  rect(480, 280, 20, 100);
  rect(450, 260, 80, 20);
  rect(150, 120, 300, 20);
  rect(275, 140, 25, 40);
  rect(100, 270, 20, 100);fill(35, 20, 219);
  rect(200, 240, 180, 30); 
  rect(0, 0, 600, 10); 
  rect(0, 0, 10, 600); 
  rect(0, 590, 600, 10);
  rect(590, 0, 10, 600);
  rect(40, 50, 50, 20);
  rect(140, 50, 50, 20);
  rect(0, 220, 40, 140);
  rect(0, 400, 40, 20);
  rect(80, 580, 200, 20);
  rect(340, 580, 200, 20);
  rect(240, 500, 150, 20);
  rect(300, 500, 20, 50);
  rect(240, 380, 150, 20);
  rect(300, 380, 20, 70);
  rect(390, 450, 60, 15);
  rect(500, 450, 90, 15);
  rect(500, 480, 20, 50);
  rect(120, 420, 20, 80);
  rect(90, 500, 90, 20);
  rect(280, 0, 20, 60);
  rect(380, 50, 40, 20);
  rect(480, 50, 40, 20);
  rect(480, 280, 20, 100);
  rect(450, 260, 80, 20);
  rect(150, 120, 300, 20);
  rect(275, 140, 25, 40);
  rect(100, 270, 20, 100);
  
 
}
 
  
 
     
      
  

  

void keyPressed()
{
  if(key==CODED)
  {
    if(keyCode==LEFT)
    {
     f1.moveLeft();
    }
    if(keyCode==RIGHT)
    {
      f1.moveRight();
    }
    if(keyCode==UP)
    {
     f1.moveUp();
    }
    if(keyCode==DOWN)
    {
     f1.moveDown();
    }
    
 
  }

}
----------------------------------------------
class Eye
{
  int diameter;
  int x;
  int y;
  int grey;
  
  Eye(int d, int xcor, int ycor, int g)
  {
    grey=g;
    diameter=d;
    x=xcor;
    y=ycor;
  }
  void display()
  {
    fill(grey);
    ellipse(x,y,diameter,diameter);
  }
  int getX()
  {
    return x;
  }
  void setX(int xx)
  {
    x=xx;
 }
   int getY()
  {
    return y;
  }
  void setY(int yy)
  {
    y=yy;
 }
 
 
 
 
}
----------------------------------------------
class Enemy
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int diameter;
  int step;
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;
  
  
  Enemy(int a,int b,int c,int d,int rc,int gc,int bc)
  {
    x=a;
    y=a;
    diameter=c;
    step=d;
    r=rc;
    g=gc;
    b=bc;
}
void display()
{ 
  fill(r, g, b);
  stroke(0,0,255);
  ellipse(x,y,diameter,diameter);
  
}

void move()
{
  y=y+step;
  if(y<diameter)
  step=-step;
  if(y>600)
  step=-step;
}
void moveUp()
{ 
  if(y>=5+diameter/2)
  {
    y=y-5;
  }
}
void moveDown()
{
  if(y<=height-5-diameter/2)
  {
    y=y+5;
  }
}

----------------------------------------------
class Face
{
  int diameter;
  int x;
  int y;
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;
  Eye leftEye;
  Eye rightEye;
  
  Face(int d, int xcor, int ycor,int rc,int gc,int bc)
  {
    diameter=d;
    y=ycor;
    x=xcor;
    r=rc;
    g=gc;
    b=bc;
    leftEye=new Eye(10,x-10,y-10,255);
    rightEye=new Eye(10,x+10,y-10,250);
  }
  void display()
  {
    fill(255, g, b);
    stroke(255,0,0);
    ellipse(x,y,diameter,diameter);
    leftEye.display();
    rightEye.display();
  }
  void moveLeft()
  {
    if(x>diameter/2)
    {
      x=x-10;
      leftEye.setX(leftEye.getX()-10);
      rightEye.setX(rightEye.getX()-10);
   }
  }
  void moveRight()
  {
    if(x<width-diameter/2)
    {
    x=x+10;
      leftEye.setX(leftEye.getX()+10);
      rightEye.setX(rightEye.getX()+10);
    }
  }
  void moveUp()
{ 
  if(y>=5+diameter/2)
  {
    y=y-10;
    leftEye.setY(leftEye.getY()-10);
    rightEye.setY(rightEye.getY()-10);
  }
}
 
    void moveDown()
{
  if(y<=height-5-diameter/2)
  {
    y=y+10;
    leftEye.setY(leftEye.getY()+10);
    rightEye.setY(rightEye.getY()+10);
    
  }
}
void changeColor()
{
  r=(r+20)%255;
}



  }
  --------------------------------------------
class Message
{
int startTime;
int stopTime;
String str;
int x;
int y;
boolean visible;

Message(int xcor, int ycor, int t1,int t2, String s)
{
  x = xcor;
  y = ycor;
  startTime = t1;
  stopTime = t2;
  str = s;
  visible = false;
}

void display()
{
  textSize(24);
  if(visible == true)
   {
     text(str, x, y);
   }
}
  
void setTime(int time)
{
    if(time>=startTime && time<= stopTime)
    {
      visible = true;   
    }
    else
    {
      visible = false;   
    }
}

----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's best to narrow down the problem and test assumptions using smaller programs the focus on that issue. At the moment you've posted a lot of code with many syntax error. You will need to fix the syntax errors one at a time.

Regarding your homework assignment goal:

> the game to stop when the face class touches the enemy class

that should be straight forward because:

- you know the position of the face instance (not class) and enemy instances.
- you know the diameter for each
- if the distance between the two is smaller than the sum of their radii then it must be a collision.

The radius is simply half the diameter and regarding distance, Processing makes this trivial with the [`dist(x1, y1, x2, y2)`](https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html) function. Simply give it the x,y coordinate pairs for the two instances (face and enemy) and it will return the distance.
(No need to manually compute Pythagoras Theorem, dist() does it for you)

Checkout this [Processing rollover example](https://processing.org/examples/rollover.html) and notice the `overCircle` function in particular. In your scenario:

```
if(dist(f1.x, f1.y, e1.x, e1.y) < ( (f1.diameter + e1.diameter) / 2) ){
  noLoop();
}
```

It's unclear if you've covered arrays and for loops yet. This would help avoid manually copy pasting and modifying the condition for the rest of the enemies.

Comment: When I put this part in my code everything stops. I don't get it.<3

Comment: Of course it stops everything :) I thought that's what you meant by "I want the game to stop". That's what [`noLoop()`](https://processing.org/reference/noLoop_.html) does: pauses the continuous loop where `draw()` is called. If you need something else instead simply replace `noLoop()` with that functionality.

Comment: I am so sorry, it's perfect sorry to say this!!! You are a lifesaver!! Thank you so much<3